# Matching across two tables in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 380,000 records in `File 1`. I have over a million in `File 2`. I wrote a simple query to return records that matched on a certain field from both.

```
select *
from file1, file2
where file1.field = file2.field
```

The problem is `file1.field` is repeated in `file2` more than once so I get 491,000 matches back. I just need the first match. Basically just looking for a flag if `file1.field` is in `file2` or not. I'm sure there is a simple operator for this, I am just a self taught beginner and don't know it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT *
FROM file1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM file2 
              WHERE file2.field = file1.field)
```

Comment: You did not display the "flag" he specifically asked for.

Comment: @RosSQL : Retrieved data is a flag itself  in the query above

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
    , (select top 1 1 from file2 f2 where f2.field=f1.field) as flag
from file1 f1
```

You will have a "1" or a NULL in a column called [flag]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the distinct key word

```
select Distinct *
from file1, file2
where file1.field = file2.field
```